# I need to draw multiple routes from my position to a predefined location on a Bing Map

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to draw multiple routes from my position to a predefined location on a Bing Map.

But I'm new to WP7, can anybody please tell me the step

And will that answer be sufficient to draw the routes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Calculating a Route Using Bing Maps SOAP Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681887.aspx) article and esspecially *Add code to calculate and display a route* sample. Thise example uses [MapPolyline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.mappolyline.aspx)  class to draw route line. You can add as many such lines as you wish.

Alternatively, please see [Bing Maps for Games with Pathfinding](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/bing_maps_pathfinding) sample and especially `RouteRender` class. This is more custom approach with XNA.